# Signal SIGABRT xcode

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I have a grid and inside of my grid there are 52 square as a button when I click my square I should go to another page but my process is terminated I don't know why?

would you please help me?

Thanks in advance!

**Hear is my YearView page (52 square are here)**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
int rows = 13, columns = 4;
UIView *buttonView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.f, 0.f, 80*columns, 32*rows)];
int currentTag = 0;

for (int y = 0; y < rows; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < columns; x++) {

        UIButton * button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom]; 
        //  [button.layer setBorderWidth:1.0]; 
        //  [button.layer setBorderColor:UIColor blackColor]];
        button.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed: 201.0/255.0 green: 201.0/255.0 blue:201.0/255.0 alpha: 1.0];
        button.tag = currentTag;
        currentTag++;
        [button.layer setBorderColor: [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
        [button.layer setBorderWidth: 1.0];
        [button setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",currentTag] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        button.frame = CGRectMake(80*x, 32*y, 80, 32); 
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [buttonView addSubview: button];

    }
}

// Center the view which contains your buttons
CGPoint centerPoint = buttonView.center;
centerPoint.x = self.view.center.x;
buttonView.center = centerPoint;
[self.view addSubview:buttonView];    

}


-(void)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)button
{
NSLog(@"button %u -- frame: %@", button.tag, NSStringFromCGRect(button.frame));
WeekView *crtObj=[[WeekView alloc]initWithNibName:@"WeekView" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:crtObj animated:YES];
// [crtObj release];


}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString: @"WeekView"]){

        // Get reference to the destination view controller
     //  WeekView *vc = [segue destinationViewController];

        // Pass any objects to the view controller here, like...
       // [vc setMyObjectHere:object];
    [segue.destinationViewController setTitle:@"WeekView"];
    }}
```

**Edit:**

*** First throw call stack:

```
 (0x13e0022 0x1571cd6 0x1388a48 0x13889b9 0x24b638 0xf11fc 0xf1779 0xf199b 0xf1d11 0x1038fd 0x103aef 0x103dbb 
  0x10485f 0x104e06 0x104a24 0x3529 0x13e1e99 0x2d14e 0x2d0e6 0xd3ade 0xd3fa7 0xd3266 0x523c0 0x525e6 0x38dc4 
 0x2c634 0x12caef5 0x13b4195 0x1318ff2 0x13178da 0x1316d84 0x1316c9b 0x12c97d8 0x12c988a 0x2a626 0x204d 0x1fb5)
 terminate called throwing an exception(lldb) 


0xbffff5b4
0xbffff6d4
```

with debugging = Signal Sigabrat start from here

```
WeekView *crtObj=[[WeekView alloc]initWithNibName:@"WeekView" bundle:nil];
```

Comment: Can you provide the error above all the (0x738978928) in the output window

Comment: Whats the exact log you getting in crash report?

Comment: Unfortunately it does not tell a lot. When you set a breakpoint, on what line does it crash?

Comment: Bart is mooning your program again! (I really hate when people misspell stuff)

Comment: Two things:  -- do you really have a "WeekView.xib" file in your project?  -- what happens if you put the `buttonPressed:` code inside a @try/@catch and log the exception's description and `callStackSymbols`?

Comment: @Oritm I got error in this line WeekView *crtObj=[[WeekView alloc]initWithNibName:@"WeekView" bundle:nil];

Comment: @PhillipMills I have storyboard and I have WeekView,my error is in this line     WeekView *crtObj=[[WeekView alloc]initWithNibName:@"WeekView" bundle:nil];

Comment: OK...just checking since storyboards and xib files in the same project are a little unusual.  :)  Maybe catching the exception will give better error information.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the storyboard but you are using

```
WeekView *crtObj=[[WeekView alloc]initWithNibName:@"WeekView" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:crtObj animated:YES];
```

i think you want to use the storyboard here:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"WeekView" sender:self];
```

Comment: should I remove  this-->> WeekView *crtObj=[[WeekView alloc]initWithNibName:@"WeekView" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:crtObj animated:YES]; and add your code stiil error

Comment: yes you should remove that, the storyboard is doing this for you. I refer to http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SecondiOSAppTutorial/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: Make sure that in the storyboard, the segue has the identifier "WeekView". To do this, click the line betweeen the 2 ViewController, and check if the identifier is WeekView. If this doesnt help. Do a clean of the project (SHIFT-COMMAND-K) and check if the error message has changed. If so, post it in the original post

Comment: yes I have WeekView as a identifier and I use (SHIFT-COMMAND-K) but still error

Comment: But where does it crash now, sinds you removed the line WeekView *crtObj=[[WeekView alloc]initWithNibName:@"WeekView" bundle:nil];

Comment: in this line [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"WeekView" sender:self];

Comment: I think theres something wrong in your structure. You can send me the project if you want, i will check it for you.. If you dont want that; this can help http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1